# jQuery libraries and code aren't working - console throwing 0 errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I have spent the last 4 hours trying to debug an issue that seems to be ghosting me.

I initially tried to implement infinite-scroll.js ( Found here : https://infinite-scroll.com/ ) and couldn't for the life of me get it to work, so I gave up for now and moved on.

I then proceeded to try to implement slidebars.js ( Found here : https://github.com/adchsm/Slidebars ) and got the same result. Absolutely nothing functioning, but the console is throwing 0 errors.

The scripts are being loaded and are visible when viewing the page source.

So I can only assume something is going wrong with my enqueue order of scripts or something along those lines.

Here is my enqueue list located in `functions.php`

```
/**
 * Enqueue scripts and styles.
 */
function sativa_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'sat-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), _S_VERSION );
    wp_style_add_data( 'sat-style', 'rtl', 'replace' );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.css', array(), true );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css', array() );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'add_google_fonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@300;400;600;800;900&display=swap', false );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'sat-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/navigation.js', array(), _S_VERSION, true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'sat-skip-link-focus-fix', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js', array(), _S_VERSION, true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'sat-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/sat-js.js', array('jquery'), true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js', array(), '20120206', true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js', array('jquery'), true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'cookie-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/js.cookie.min.js', array('jquery'), true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'slide-bars-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/slidebars.js', array('jquery'), true );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'slide-bars-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/slidebars.css', array(), true );

    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sat_scripts' );
```

Below is the code implemented according to the sliders instructions:

In `archive-product.php` just below the `</header>` tag I have:

```
<div canvas="container">
    </div>

    <div off-canvas="id-1 left reveal">
    </div>

    <script>
      ( function ( $ ) {
        // Initialize Slidebars
        var controller = new slidebars();
        controller.init();

        // Toggle Slidebars
        $( '.toggle-id-1' ).on( 'click', function ( event ) {
          // Stop default action and bubbling
          event.stopPropagation();
          event.preventDefault();

          // Toggle the Slidebar with id 'id-1'
          controller.toggle( 'id-1' );
        } );
      } ) ( jQuery );
    </script>


<div class="container shop-section">
    <button class="toggle-id-1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Use our Advanced Filters to find the perfect product.">FILTER</button>
```

Any help appreciated as I feel this is probably the cause of many of my pains. I can't seem to figure out why these libraries aren't functions despite throwing 0 errors in the console nor in Query Monitor.

Comment: Try loading jquery before the other libraries. I think it is a dependency so should be loaded first.

Comment: Agreed. I've tried moving it around to no avail.

Comment: You need to test if jQuery is even working. Add more console.log to place like just inside the slidebar click handler. Console.log something like ("I got clicked!") would at least tell you if jQuery based click handler is working. If nothing there, that tells you one of two things... Either you attached to wrong object, or jQuery is not working.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to enqueue jQuery files, it's a part of WordPress code, you can just add it as a dependency (as you already did).

But your problem is that you're targeting your button (with `$( '.toggle-id-1' )`) in your script BEFORE it actually appears on the page - your script goes ABOVE your HTML. That's why jQuery just doesn't find that element and ignores all stuff you want to assign to the click event.

Notice that you load all scripts in the footer (which is a proper way to do that), so all you have to do is move your custom script in the footer (before `</body>`) or move it into a single file and enqueue it with `wp_enqueue_script` providing all dependencies you need.